# What time/date do you stamp your deployed data/exe files when they appear on the target system?

Tags: file, installation, revision, datetime

It seems a good and clean thing to ensure that your deployed files appear on the target system with a consistent time/date. Many Applications seem to do this but other than for care of overwriting Users' existing data I guess it has no real significance. I'm having a purge on my installer packaging and I'd like to know if there any good reasons for specific date/time handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Installer uses the timestamp information on files (in [some situations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368599%28VS.85%29.aspx)) in addition to the [REINSTALLMODE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371182%28VS.85%29.aspx) property to determine which files should be updated (e.g. "o" means only replace a file if the existing copy is older).

I believe the default behavior is to leave the files timestamped for their original creation (not their installation onto the user's machine). Unless you have a specific reason to do something different, I would follow the default behavior.